# Missing geocoding parametr

Tags: geocoding, folium, geocode

[This is my dataframe view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfXdj.png)

```
from cartoframes.data.services import Geocoding

gc = Geocoding()

london_stations_gdf, london_stations_metadata = gc.geocode(
        df,
        street='Borough',
        city={'value': 'London'},
        country={'value': 'United Kingdom'}
    )
```

ValueError: Credentials attribute is required. Please pass a `Credentials` instance or use the `set_default_credentials` function.

Error relate with Geocoding parametrs. however use gc = Geocoding(credentials=None), return me same error.

Comment: What module are you using to Geocode?

Comment: l import Geocoding from cartoframes.data.services and then data.

Comment: Assuming you have creds, are you including the `set_default_credentials` function?

Comment: Try set_default_credentials('creds.json'), but make error: FileNotFoundError: There is no default credentials file. Run `Credentials(...).save()` to create a credentials file. Should l place this json file in folder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have creds (username and api_key)

If you need to create the creds.json file, run the following

```
from cartoframes.auth import Credentials

Credentials('my_username', 'my_api_key').save('creds.json')
```

then modify your code to set your [default credentials](https://carto.com/developers/cartoframes/guides/Authentication/#:%7E:text=Credentials%20class%20is%20used%20to,to%20manage%20different%20CARTO%20accounts.)

```
from cartoframes.auth import set_default_credentials
from cartoframes.data.services import Geocoding

# set your default creds
set_default_credentials('path/to/your/creds.json')

gc = Geocoding()

london_stations_gdf, london_stations_metadata = gc.geocode(
        df,
        street='Borough',
        city={'value': 'London'},
        country={'value': 'United Kingdom'}
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Bob for detailing. l do not have API key and username, tried to create API but as l see it for previous. (Hey! This content applies only to previous CARTO products).      https://carto.com/help/tutorials/your-dashboard-overview/

Comment: Not sure on that one